# Can't put script inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a script like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

      // TODO: Make class toggle logic more efficient

      // Global variables
      var maxChoiceCount = 2;

      // DOM elements
      var choiceItems   = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li");
      var maxCountLabel = document.getElementById("max-count");

      // Update max count label
      maxCountLabel.textContent = maxChoiceCount;

      // Checklist item handler
      var checkItem = function() {
        activeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li.active");

        if (activeItems.length === maxChoiceCount) {
          if (this.className === "active") {
            this.className = "";
          }
        } else {
          if (this.className === "active") {
            this.className = "";
          } else {
            this.className = "active";
          }
        }
      }

      // Handle logic to enforce max count
      for (var i = 0, l = choiceItems.length; i < l; ++i) {
        choiceItems[i].onclick = checkItem
      }
    });
```

The function just for give a sign for a selected `<li>`.
I put this script inside index.js and I call it on my html page like this:

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

and it didn't work, it got error in console and said like this:

`**index.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: activeItems is not defined**`

but when I copy the script and put inside the html, it work fine.

Why cant I store it on my `index.js`?

I don't like to put many script inside my html.

**Here is the fiddle.**
https://jsfiddle.net/ddnvraf8/

Comment: did you put <script src="index.js"></script> after the jquery script call?

Comment: Does anything match the query `".boxParent li.active"` in your HTML?

Comment: yap. its match .boxParent li.active to my html and i put index.js after jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `var` on the `activeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li.active");` line.

```
var activeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li.active");
```

Because it seems to be not initialized.

Comment: I'm just quite new on javascripting though, so I thought that adding a `var` will help to define the variable.

Comment: Adding `var` makes it a local variable. Without it the variable is global, that's the only difference.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek
Thanks. But making it global, so does it mean that there is already a declared value outside?

Comment: No it means that once that statement is executed `activeItems` is defined globally and can be used past the current scope. Doing `activeItems = ...` does declare the variable, it just makes it global.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek
I see. Just quite new in Javascript. I'm usually coding on C#, then PHP and javascript/jquery. Thanks by the way. :)

Comment: Seems like it's possible the OP was using strict-mode, meaning they didn't really copy the exact code from the script into their file and there is more to their code then they are saying there is. strict-mode prohibits the use of any global variables and will instantly throw an error if any are used.

Comment: Good to note that making a variable global in this manner is a bad idea.  Use `window.` in front of your variable to make it global from within a lower scope.  For that matter it's best to avoid global variables whenever you can.  If two functions (accidentally) rely on the same global variable name, ugly side effects can ensue.  A ton more here: https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478

Comment: yeah im using strict-mode on my index.js. kind of my bad sir

Answer (score 1):

the problem just like the other guy who delete his post. i didnt add **var**
in activeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li.active");
so it have to  `var activeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li.active");` why u delete ur post dude cant give a thumbs up.

Comment: Most if not all browsers will allow you to declare a var without the `var` operator.  It just puts the var in the global scope.  Note that this is very poor form, and should be avoided.  Use window.varName to add to the global scope, if necessary.  Because you're seeing this error, it sounds like your file is in strict mode.  This disallows declaring global vars in the manner you were doing.  More on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: @JohnAtNotion I'm not certain on this, but isn't it required to have `"use strict";` in order to use strict mode? If so I would assume was directly coping their code and not adding anything else. But that defiantly can explain the error if they are.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, I believe so.  I just couldn't think of any other reason it would throw the error, so I was guessing "use strict" was in the file (but not noted in the question).

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason why you are getting this error is because you are placing your JavaScript file in [**Strict mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), which prohibits the use of any global variables. Since `activeItems` is declared globally strict mode would give the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: activeItems is not defined

Note being in strict mode means you have `"use strict";` somewhere in your JS file, commonly at the top:

```
"use strict";

// Other code
```

Under normal JavaScript (*not in strict-mode*), despite global variables commonly being known as bad practice, you code would work functionally the same in this case and have no errors. The solution would be to make the variable local:

```
var activeItems = ... ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">.box{
  max-width:240px;
}
.box h4{
    margin: 4px 15px;
}
.boxParent li:last-child{
  border-bottom: solid thin #d8d8d8
}
.boxParent li.active:after{
    content: "\2713";
    color: #F8E74E;
}

.boxParent li:after {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 24px;
}
.boxParent li.active {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}</style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h4>Categories</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="boxCaption">
    <h3 style="display:none;">Select up to <span id="max-count">0</span> choices</h3>
    <ul class="boxParent">
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit </li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In index.js :

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

          // TODO: Make class toggle logic more efficient

          // Global variables
          var maxChoiceCount = 2;

          // DOM elements
          var choiceItems   = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li");
          var maxCountLabel = document.getElementById("max-count");

          // Update max count label
          maxCountLabel.textContent = maxChoiceCount;

          // Checklist item handler
          var checkItem = function() {
            activeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li.active");

            if (activeItems.length === maxChoiceCount) {
              if (this.className === "active") {
                this.className = "";
              }
            } else {
              if (this.className === "active") {
                this.className = "";
              } else {
                this.className = "active";
              }
            }
          }

          // Handle logic to enforce max count
          for (var i = 0, l = choiceItems.length; i < l; ++i) {
            choiceItems[i].onclick = checkItem
          }
        });
```

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

activeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li.active");

Your variable is undeclared.

var activeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxParent li.active");